# Let $(x,y)$ be the smallest solution $\in \mathbb N^+$ of $x^2+xy-y^2=0$, then $y-x<x$. Why?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

The book shows why $x^2+xy-y^2=0$ doesn't have any solutions in $\mathbb N^+$:

> Let $(x,y)$ be the solution with smallest $x \in \mathbb N^+$ of $x^2+xy-y^2=0$ (where $y$ must be $> x$).
>
> Then $(y-x,x)$ is also a solution, but with smaller first coefficient. Contradiction.

How can I deduce that $y-x$ is smaller than $x$? I understand that this is true for bigger solutions (constructed with $(y,x+y)$), but here it's not as obvious to me.

---

For instance, the first solutions of $x^2+xy-y^2=1$ are

```
1  0  1  1  ..
0  1  1  2  ..
```

So $(0,1)$ is the solution with smallest $x$ yet $y-x$ is not smaller. The analogy is faulty since one equation has infinitely many solutions while the other has none, but this is just to demonstrate my misunderstanding.

Comment: What is $\Bbb N_1$?

Comment: I ask because my guess is that $0\notin \Bbb N_1$...

Comment: @Grantwalzer usually $\mathbb N^+$.  Actually $\mathbb Z^+$ is more probably more common, as the time travelling user after me will point out.

Comment: Or $\Bbb Z^+{}$.

Comment: For contradiction. Assume $y-x\not < x$. But then $y\ge 2x$, so $y(y-x)-x^2=0\ge 2x(2x-x)-x^2=x^2\,\Rightarrow\, x=0$, contradiction.

Comment: why didn't he just say "with smallest $y \in \Bbb N^+$" instead !?!?

Comment: Use infinite descent. mod $3$ implies $x\equiv y\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. So: $(x,y)$ is a solution $\iff \, (x/3,y/3)$ is a solution. Impossible if $x,y\in\Bbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ x^2 + x y - y^2 = 0,  \; \;  y > x > 0 $$
$$ x^2 = y (y-x) $$
all items positive
$$ \frac{x}{y} = \frac{y-x}{x} $$ and
$$ \frac{x}{y} < 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

The given solution relies on establishing that any solution for $$\{(x, y) ~:~ x^2 + xy - y^2 = 0\}$$

has the property that $y - x < x$, or that $y < 2x$.  One way to establish this is just to solve the equation for $y$:

$$y= \frac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2} x \approx 1.618 x < 2x$$

A simpler approach would be to just inspect the equation $\pmod 2$, and see that all solutions must be even, which to infinite descent.  Or as mercio pointed out in the comments, just establish the descent by looking at the second elements of $(x, y)$ and $(y - x, x)$, since $y > x$.